# How can I pass a string into a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I can't figure out how to pass a string into a javascript function... how to do it?

```
onclick="functionName(1, "Text goes here!")"
```

I've tried:

```
onclick="functionName(1, \""Text goes here!"\")"
onclick="functionName(1, ""Text goes here!"")"
onclick="functionName(1, \"Text goes here!\")"
```

Nothing works, I keep getting the "unexpected token" error...

Comment: See the duplicate for your answer, however it should be noted that the `onclick` attribute is incredibly outdated and you should not be using it. Attach your events unobtrusively using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, and avoid this problem in the first place.

Comment: You can use Template literals: \`string text\`